# What is the use of $value in Angular2?

Tags: angular

What is the API Reference/Angular2 Concept for the use of `$value` in the below code sample?

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  <li class="text">
    {{item.$value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

API Reference https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

The above snippet is taken from https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array that is received through the `items` observable contains objects that have a `$value` property.

A structure like this:

```
[
  {
    $value: 'something',
    (...)
  },
  (...)
  {
    $value: 'something else',
    (...)
  },
]
```